# New x-axis does not show up

Tags: r, graph

I have a dataset with values which depend on days. There are over 6000 days in the dataset.I would like to see some of the days on the x-axis of my graph.

```
dates <- as.Date(YEN[,1], "%d.%m.%Y")
YEN <- as.xts(YEN[,2], dates)
plot(YEN, xaxt= 'n', ylab="Exchange rate", xlab= "Time")
```

With this I have created a graph with no values on the x-axis.

I now want the 1st, 1000th and 3000th day to be shown on the x-axis.

```
Axis(side=1, at=1:3, labels= dates(c[1,2000,3000])
```

R gives no error warning but is not drawing a new axis with the requested values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your command (i) can't work as you expect, (ii) contains wrong syntax, and (iii) doesn't close all parentheses and thus isn't executed.

Comment: `axis` is more user-friendly I think. And you just have your brackets and parentheses swapped `Axis(side=1, at=1:3, labels= dates[c(1,2000,3000)])`